# What is the best way to identify planar objects in an image with computer vision?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I need to draw bounds around some planar objects like books, cigarette boxes etc. Can anybody give me advice what kind of software I need to recognize all medicine in drugstore. Because there are different drug count on identical medicine and I need to recognize that difference.

I try to use OpenCV SURF feature detector, but it works fine only when one object presents on picture. Than I try to use YOLOv3 neuronet. It works better and faster, but it made for detecting any kind of similar objects like cars, persons etc and I think that it is overkill for my task.

Comment: I think your question is too broad, this problem is not trivial at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use YOLOv3 but train your network for the classes you need to detect only, you can use [this](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/) to do the training.